# How to join two tables ids with auto increment

Tags: mysql

How can i join two tables ids both are `AUTO_INCREMENT` i need result like this i am showing  example below. what i want.

```
Table1                 |                Table2
-----------------------|-----------------------
userid | name | f_name |userid | work | study 
-----------------------|-----------------------
1      |  ali |  amjad |1      | yes  | no
-----------------------|-----------------------
2      |  aff | mff    |2      |no    |yes
```

`Table1` and `Table2` userid should be same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.userid, t1.name, t1.f_name, t2.userid, t2.work, t2.study
FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2
ON t1.userid = t2.userid
```

Comment: yes this one good way but i need if data insert on table 1 than automatically create new row in table two with same userid weather table2 rows empty.

Comment: Well you havent mentioned anything like this in your question anyway to achieve this you will need to create a trigger on your Table1 which will record the Identity value of any new inserted record and will insert the a new row into table table2. For this you do not need to have an identity column in table2 since it will be inserting values only from table1.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this,

```
  select Table1.userid,Table1.name,Table1.f_name,Table2.userid, Table2.work,Table2.study from Table1, Table2 where Table1.userid=Table2.userid
```